# Learning how to create blog via RoR, and got unexpected content on index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unexpectendoffile

i'm just started making blog via RoR, using blog-from-scratch guide and i've got some unexpected content on my index page. Here is the picture:
http://i.minus.com/ibpnYRmlPv7IW3.png
Some hash-like string under the title is that unexpected thing.

**index_page code:**

```
<h1>Recent posts</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Text</th>
   </tr>

   <%= @posts.each do |post| %>
        <tr>
            <td style="border: solid 2px;"><%= post.title %></td>
            <td style="border: solid 2px;"><%= post.text %></td>
       </tr>
   <% end %>    
</table>


<%= link_to 'New post', :action => :new %>
```

**Code part from PostsController:**

```
def index
    @posts = Post.all
end
```

First i thought that was kind a time stamp from Db, but here is
 
**code from migrate:**

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :text
    end
  end
end
```

So now any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<%= @posts.each do |post| %>
```

to

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
```

What you're seeing is `@posts.to_s` output at the top of the screenshot from the

```
<%= @posts...
```